# 2001 Chevrolet can’t remember the rest it a truck

Tags: starting, chevrolet, alternator, truck

Okay so when I went to crank the truck the lights where on but the moment I went to start it nothing evening went out change the battery still nothing can it be my alternator or something

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: check the battery cable connections where the terminals are crimped on. Look for oxidation of the wires. Also check other end of the ground wire to see if that side is not ground to chassis well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it that is not a symptom of a faulty alternator.

If you are certain that the replacement battery is good, and that nothing happens, no clicking or noises, and the dash lights go out, then I would first suspect a fault with the ignition switch.

If the ignition switch can become faulty where it does not keep power on to the vehicles electric system when it is moved into the start position.

This could easily be checked using a multimeter.

If there is clicking of the starter solenoid or relays when you try to start the vehicle then I would first check the connections to the battery.  Make sure that all connections are clean.